# How to close a Google Maps InfoWindows by clicking a link inside the InfoWindow itself?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a Google Maps with InfoWindow.
Inside the infowindow I have a text and, at the end of it, a link "Open" which open a div above the map.
Now, I would like to close the infowindow while clicking on the link "Open".

This is the code I use to open the div

```js
// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
var gmarkers = [];
var map = null;

function initialize() {
    // create the map
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.519243, -0.126661),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-big"),
        myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5608308012934, -0.0540925428914196);
    var marker = createMarker(point, " Clapton ", "<div class='scrittafumetto' id='proprieta_4940'><strong><div class='titolo'> Title</div></strong><br /><a class='mostra_vedi'>Vedi</a></span></div>");
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(marker, i) {
    var marker_id = marker.id;


    if ($('#new-overview-main_' + marker_id).css('display') == 'block') {
        $('#new-overview-main_' + marker_id).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('#new-overview-main_' + marker_id).css('display', 'block');
    }

});

function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    // add a line to the side_bar html
}
```

Then, when I click on "Vedi" I open a div above the map by using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.scrittafumetto', function(event){
    var marker_id = $(this).attr('id');
    infoWindowClosed = true;
    marker_id = marker_id.replace("proprieta_", "");
    $('.new-overview-main').css('display', 'none');
    if ($('#new-overview-main_'+marker_id).css('display') == 'block') {
        $('#new-overview-main_'+marker_id).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('#new-overview-main_'+marker_id).css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

I thought that

```
infoWindowClosed = true;
```

would have done the trick, but it doesn't work.

Any tip?

Thanks, Dean.

Comment: can you add the code you're using to create the infowindows please

Comment: No problem, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you've already got `infowindow` as a global variable.  You should just be able to call the `close()` method on it, from inside the event listener you've got for the click on the 'Open'.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.scrittafumetto', function(event){
    infowindow.close();
    ...
}
```

Comment: On the same code, is there any way to change marker colour?

Comment: Aha, that's a whole other question! ;-) yes there is, you can use your gmarkers array, but it might take a bit more code to get that working. Ask it as a new question and you'll get some proper help with that